# wkhtmltopdf duplicates table row on next page

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I'm converting HTML that contains tables into a PDF file using `wkhtmltopdf` on Linux (AWS Lambda). Generally, it works well however it has a problem when table starts before the end of page 1 and ends on page 2. Table header is duplicated over a row on page 2.

[image]

**What can I do to prevent this issue?**

`$ ./wkhtmltopdf --version
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3-dev-79ff51e (with patched qt)`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: Don't use `<thead>` tag and nothing is repeated on the next page.